# Do I need to check if there are elements in the array/list or not before looping through it?

Tags: loops, if-statement

Two examples:

## Python

```
my_list = []
if my_list:
    for item in my_list: ...
# or just
for item in my_list
```

## PHP

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "...");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while (mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {}
}
// or just
while(mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {}
```

Is there any difference assuming that I am not aware of notifying user if the list or mysql result is empty by prompting a message like "You have no letters in your mailbox!" for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it is a matter of preference. Though, it would make more sense to do the

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
while (mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {}
}
```

In this case, depending on how many rows you get back, you could do other things, rather than just check it once. But again, its a preference, and if you know you will never check it again, it would make your code cleaner to do it the second way.

Answer (score 0):

For a foreach style construct that uses iterators, there is no benefit to checking beforehand and in some cases might actually result in performing an expensive calculation twice. The iterators themselves have to check for the presence of data to do their work so adding an additional check adds no value. Adding checks like that simply makes your code more difficult to read so you should just leave it out.